# Strange C++ Builder Linker error DATA.BIND.OBJECTSCOPE.OBJ

Tags: linker-errors, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

So I recompiled a perfectly fine and working project and suddenly all I get is this linker error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'DATA.BIND.OBJECTSCOPE.OBJ'
```

The project is a C++ console application with VCL enabled and I have no idea where the `DATA.BIND.OBJECTSCOPE.OBJ` comes from.

These are the headers I'm using.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <vcl.h>
#include <System.hpp>
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Zip.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <System.IniFiles.hpp>
```

I tried to do a complete disc clean, removing all temp files etc... No change...
This project was compiling fine yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution on Embarcadero bug tracker:

Add the followind to one of your source files

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(_WIN64)

#pragma link "Data.Bind.ObjectScope.obj"

#endif
```

The original solution ha been provided here. 
https://plus.google.com/103589122222763968447/posts/gSwPfUZLPEH

Answer (score 3):

I'll add this here if someone else stumbles upon this highly frustrating issue.

I had this exact problem. It occurred when I included `REST.Client.hpp` in an Embarcadero RAD Studio project which uses C++ Builder. After some wasted hours I ended up dropping the REST Client component onto a GUI designer form. Boom. Works. It was [this site](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CB52512/obj-files-are-missing) that lead me onto the right track.

It says that #pragma link entries are included in source files automatically when you put a component onto a form.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this is caused when a library or control that your project uses decides that it needs `DATA.BIND.OBJECTSCOPE` (e.g., due to a `uses` clause in Delphi code or a `#pragma link` in C++Builder code).

A quick but not at all elegant fix:

- Determine which `.lib` file includes this `.obj` file.  (You can do this by going to the libraries directories for RAD Studio and for any third-party libraries you're using and grepping for the `.obj` filename, or the TLIB command can list the `.obj` files in a `.lib`.)
- Edit your `.cbproj` file in a text editor to add that library to the `LinkPackageStatics` and `AllPackageLibs` sections.

Depending on your project settings (whether or not you're using runtime packages, whether you're linking statically or dynamically), you may be able to go under Project Options, Packages and under Project Options, Packages, Runtime Packages and edit package lists there, instead of editing the `.cbproj` directly.

Comment: This is a Console App so there is no `uses` nor `#pragma link`. I had static linking turned on. However, your solution was not the one that fixed the problem, but you pointed me in the right direction. I simply created a new project and copied my code over and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers, as none of the above answers fixed my project, having the same linker error.

Including the Vcl.Bind.Consts.hpp header, i.e.

```
#include "Vcl.Bind.Consts.hpp"
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error when adding RESTClient component to package project. Including the following .bpi files fixed it for me:

- vcl.bpi
- bindcomp.bpi
- bindengine.bpi
- RESTComponents.bpi

to find them look inside the $(BCB) folder. In my case, the path was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0

Additionaly, It seems like using #pragma link "name.bpi" will do the trick as well.